# Kotlin compile works, mvn compile and intellij run-app does not

Tags: java, spring, maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm having a very odd issue which I cannot explain.

I've made an artifact using gitlab ci, which I'm now importing as a dependency in another project using maven.

When I import this into the new project, I get some very strange behaviour in regards to the classes in the imported dependency. These behaviours are as follows:

- In Java files (Test.java), the package is found and Intellij reports no issues. I can even navigate to the source code in the library.
  [image]

[image]

- In Kotlin files, Intellij complains that this package cannot be found. I can't navigate to the source code as the IDE says "unresolved reference". If I do a maven artifact search, it is found but adding it makes no difference as the dependency is already in my project.
  [image]

[image]

[image]

- maven compile/package also complains that this package cannot be found
  [image]

The dependency is definitely present:
[image]

I've tried the following:

- Reimporting maven projects
- Invalidating caches
- Changing java versions, 8 - 11

The artifact is written in java 11 if that makes any difference.

Please help, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: try and do `mvn -U clean install` in the intellij terminal of that project. If that doesn't help, it might be worth showing us the dependency part of your pom.xml.

Comment: Try to close the project and the IDE, open the project root directory in OS file explorer and delete all .iml files and the .idea directory. Then re-import the project selecting pom.xml file. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#open-project .

Comment: Also, to make sure it is an IDE issue try executing `mvn clean install` from the command line outside of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those that answered!

After a long 24 hours of debugging, it turns out the issue is related to how intellij & maven look for packages in dependencies.

I was compiling with the spring-boot-maven-plugin which was building the jar with a top BOOT-INF directory, and the package structure below this.

This meant both intellij and maven were confused as they seemed to be able to find the package but not build it.

I've since removed the plugin and left now just compile with the kotlin-maven-plugin which has the package structure at the top level of the jar.

Now when I import into a project, the project can find and compile this dependency.